# Tracking jQuery 'Modal' opening time, with GA4 and GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'd like to know how many seconds a user keeps a modal opened with Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager. I'm not using Analytics Universal, so I guess I can just use GTM events.

I see the activator "Timer", but I don't know how to use it. I can activate it using `Percent Visible` (to know when it's open) and `Click Classes` (to watch the popup element), so it will send a ping each XXX seconds. But how can I know the total time?
And which TAG should I use?

-- ADDITIONAL INFO

I'm using a jQuery modal. So basically it's a DIV hidden, that will show pressing a button. Clicking outside the modal, or clicking the closing button will hide again the DIV. For this reason I can use `Percent Visible` that pings each xxx seconds if % visible is > 0.

Thank you

===

Comment: I think there is something to make sure first. 1. If the user leave your website directly with the pop-up shows. Do you need to count the time as well? 2. How can we define the users close the pop-up. Is your pop-up only have a button to close?

Comment: I've answered adding details to the question. Btw the popup is a Jquery modal, so it uses the CSS style 'display'. From GTM, I can use the "activator" trigger "Percent Visible" on the modal DIV. Clicking outside will close the popup. closing the page will stop the TIMER event

Comment: I'm renaming all my uses of "popup" in "modal"

Answer (score 1):

Came up a solution here

### Set up the timer when pop-up shows

Create the `Tag` and select `Custom Html`

Here is the code

```html
<script>
(function(){
  // Trigger this when your popup show
  var currentTime =  Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  window.myPopupShowTime = currentTime;
})()
</script>
```

Basically it just get the current timestamp and assign to the `window.myPopupShowTime`

### Calculate the difference when the pop-up close

```html
<script>
(function(){
  // Trigger this when your popup close
  var showLastTime = false;
  var currentTime =  Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  var startTime = window.myPopupShowTime || 0;
  if(startTime != 0){
    showLastTime = currentTime - startTime;
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({event : "get_popup_show_time" ,  showLastTime : showLastTime})
  }  
})()
</script>
```

At this point, I calculate the difference between the close and show. In case there is a error when setting start time. If we don't have the start time, we don't calculate.

Then I push another datalayer event so you can use it to track for your own event with the seconds.

### Result

[image]

And if you want to get the milliseconds.
Just remove the `/ 1000` for both `Tags`